# Overcoming Gmail's "Display Images Below" (HTML email/media queries)

Tags: html, css, email, media-queries, html-email

I'm making an HTML email that has a mobile and desktop version. The way I'm accomplishing this is by making two separate tables, one with an id of #desktop and the other with one as #mobile. At a certain point with a media query (around 450px) I set display for #desktop to none, and it works. On my phone, only the mobile version shows up as expected; however, on desktop, when prompted with the "Display Images Below" from gmail, after clicking it, the mobile version of the email shows up below the desktop version (even though it's display is naturally set to none).

Now. I've tried a million ways to fix this. I've tweaked the media queries. I gave #mobile a margin to hide it, I changed all the images to background-images, but for some reason no matter what I do I can't get around this... has anyone had a similar experience where they found a solution?

Comment: perhaps you should put your code as well

Answer (score 0):

I think i know whats happening here and since you havent given any code to go with i will take a stab in the dark. For mobile verison to hide completely, you need the images to be set at 1px x 1px or 0px x 0px.

You are controling the mobile version using CSS so each you can target each of the images and give it a width of 100% and height auto important.

Let me know if it works for you.